# Changing time of drweb update

Tags: centos

Our drweb update is running daily at around 00:30 each day, we are looking to change this to 05:00.

I've found the drweb-update file in the cron.d folder but not sure what to change:

```
*/30 * * * * drweb /opt/drweb/update.pl
```

We're running Centos5 and Plesk.

Thanks in advance

Comment: that cron line says its running every 30 minutes not that it runs at 00:30, probably better to leave as is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cron entry needs to look like so:

```
* 5 * * * drweb /opt/drweb/update.pl
```

The 5 entries are:

```
min day dayofmonth month dayofweek
```

See `man 5 crontab` for details.